# Rank of string solution

Tags: algorithm, string-algorithm

I was going through a question where it asks you to find the rank of the string amongst its permutations sorted lexicographically.

O(N^2) is pretty clear.

Some websites have [O(n) solution](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographic-rank-of-a-string/) also. The part that is optimized is basically pre-populating a `count array` such that

> count[i] contains count of characters which are present in str and are smaller than i.

I understand that this'd reduce the complexity but can't fit my head around how we are calculating this array. This is the function that does this (taken from the link):

```
// Construct a count array where value at every index
// contains count of smaller characters in whole string
void populateAndIncreaseCount (int* count, char* str)
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; str[i]; ++i )
        ++count[ str[i] ];

    for( i = 1; i < 256; ++i )
        count[i] += count[i-1];
}
```

Can someone please provide an intuitive explanation of this function?

Comment: The implementation in that source is pretty bad - `int mul` will overflow for any string longer than 12 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood after going through it again. Got confused due to wrong syntax in c++. It's actually doing a pretty simple thing (Here's the java version :

```
void populateAndIncreaseCount(int[] count, String str) {
    // count is initialized to zero for all indices
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
      count[str.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 256; ++i)
      count[i] += count[i - 1];
  }
```

After first step, indices whose character are present in string are non-zero. Then, for each index in count array, it'd be the sum of all the counts till `index-1` since array represents lexicographically sorted characters. And, after each search, we udate the count array also:

// Removes a character ch from count[] array
// constructed by populateAndIncreaseCount()

```
void updatecount (int* count, char ch)
{
    int i;
    for( i = ch; i < MAX_CHAR; ++i )
        --count[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That solution is doing a [Bucket Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) and then sorting the output.

A bucket sort is `O(items + number_of_possible_distinct_inputs)` which for a fixed alphabet can be advertised as `O(n)`.

However in practice UTF makes for a pretty large alphabet.  I would therefore suggest a quicksort instead.  Because a quicksort that divides into the three buckets of `<`, `>` and `=` is efficient for a large character set, but still takes advantage of a small one.